# Pass HttpPostedFileBase as an Argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an application that allows users to upload word and pdf documents.  I also have a class in my model that gathers some metadata about the file (i.e., file size, content type, etc.).

I want to centralize some of the "save" functionality (both saving the metadata to the database, and saving the actual file to the server).  I would like to pass the HttpPostedFileBase to my Service layer that will then use the built-in .SaveAs(filename) functionality.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the file type to another method.  I've tried the below:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedDocument)
{
    string fileName = "asdfasdf";

    SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();

    //this works fine
    uploadedDocument.SaveAs(fileName)

    //this does not work
    foo.Save(uploadedDocument, fileName);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void Save(HttpPostedFile file, string fileName)
    {
        //database save
        file.SaveAs(fileName);
    }
}
```

When I try to pass the HttpPostedFile into the Save method on SomeClass, there is a compiler error (because in the above, uploadedDocument is of type HttpPostedFileBase, not HttpPostedFile).

However, if I try to cast uploadedDocument to HttpPostedFile, it does not work.

So, specifically, how can I pass an HttpPostedFileBase to another method?  Or, more generally, if I were to pass the HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream to another method, how can I save that document to the server? Note that the document is not an image and I am not streaming the response to the user, so writing to the response stream isn't appropriate...I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use [`HttpPostedFileBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx), for example in the SomeClass.Save method.  The [`HttpPostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) class doesn't actually derive from the [`HttpPostedFileBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx), so you're bound to get the compiler error you noticed.  You might also see the documentation for [`HttPostedFileWrapper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilewrapper.aspx) which is used for the reverse scenario: passing [`HttpPostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) to a method that accepts [`HttpPostedFileBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx).